# How to send Chrome browser to URL with the mouse (without hitting the Enter key)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, mouse, mouse-click

I'm using Chrome because I'm finding it slightly faster than Firefox. However there was one nifty feature that Firefox has which Chrome doesn't seem to have. When I cut and paste a link with the mouse and paste it into Chrome's URL bar, I would like to be able to click somewhere in the Chrome user interface to send the browser to the site corresponding to the pasted URL, but unlike Firefox, Chrome doesn't seem to have such a button, thus requiring me to take my left hand off the mouse and hit Enter on the keyboard (thus somewhat slowing computer usage besides the fact that such movement is not very ergonomically friendly as it also involves bending the wrist a little bit).

So, does anyone know how to send Chrome to a URL using just the mouse (after cuting or copying and then pasting a URL into the Chrome web address bar with the mouse)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a URL on the clipboard, right-click in the Address Bar and select `Paste and go`